# Framework/application to have inmemory copy of DataBase data

Tags: java, database, enterprise-library

We have a requirement to have a In Memory copy of data from our different Relational DB servers.

Also keep the memory image updated if data in Relational DB servers is changing.

is there any framework/application we can utilize to serve this requirement.

Comment: Do you want to explore options of in memory db in which case hsql db is a popular choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have something in memory is not requirement, requirement is a reson for that - what is the reason ? **ORMs** (Hibernate, EclipseLink etc.) usually do some **caching**, if it's not enough, try some **caches** (EHcache, JBoss Cache, ...) and set some cache loaders for them (look at Apple's EOM for inspiration, it's quite simple).

Comment: got your point. Our goal to is have frequently used data from multipl erelational DBs in memory so that multiple systems have faster access to it rather than each going to DB.

Comment: can u elaborate more on Cache Loaders. How do they fit into picture here?

Comment: Cache loader is a class/method reponsible for loading data to cache data that are not there. They take care about inserts and re-loading of expired/evicted objects.

If you objects are updated, you'll have to set expiration/eviction policies (when you know the update period) and/or some cache request interceptors. 

I've not used that for some time so I cannot provide more details.